# How to apply css style for a span containing an active link

Tags: html, css

I currently have 2 links enclosed within 2 spans however when a link is clicked an dis active, the link has a class"linkActive". I need to apply a border for the span containing the active link how can one do this in css styles

```
     HTML
        <div>
           <span class="sec">
              <a>Link1</a>
           </span>
           <span class="sec">
             <a class="linkActive">Link2</a>
           </span>
        </div>
```

I would like to apply border to span containing the anchor tag with link active class

```
 i tried    span.sec a.linkActive{
                 border-bottom: 3px solid black;
             }
```

It does not seem to work. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: There is no parent selector in css. You can use jquery for that. Otherwise just apply the border to your anchor like you posted. Your code is working. http://jsfiddle.net/cdku8agp/

Comment: Doggone it, I meant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector is the dupe. Flag dialog, y u no work?

Answer (score 1):

you can add border to a itself using pseudo element

```css
div span {
  display: inline-block;
}
div span a {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  position: relative;
}
div span a.linkActive:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background: black;
  height: 3px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="sec"><a>Link1</a></span>
  <span class="sec"><a class="linkActive">Link2</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not affect a parent element only via CSS, you have to use js.

jQuery

```
$('span.sec > a').click(function() {
   $(this).closest('span').css({'border-bottom': '3px solid black'});
})s;
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/ubyxcaor/

Use CSS selector [class=linkActive]

```
<style>
span a[class=linkActive] {border: solid thin green;}
</style>
```